# Addition cement slab

Tags: foundation, cement, backyard, addition

Should an addition of cement slab be attached to house foundation?? I do not know any information about this pretty new at all this planning on getting a 18x30

Comment: Does it need to (ie: step at doorway, roof or deck support, new house that has settled out, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if the slab is meant to support an addition that is tied into the existing building structure then you should be aiming to provide a below grade foundation or footing that is equivalent to that of the existing structure.

It is also highly advisable to tie any footings or foundation walls together via rebar that is drilled and adhesive bonded into the existing structure.

The goal that you are aiming for is to prevent any differential movement between the new and old foundations. Such movement can result in cracks in walls, doors and windows not fitting properly and unnecessary added stress to the existing structure.

Keep in mind that any project requiring permitting will almost for sure require plans and blue prints prepared by a properly licensed structural engineer.

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciate all the information. We are just planning on using it as a patio